# Array syntax is not valid

Tags: beanshell

I try to do a simple thing,  split text and put result in an array

```
public void testSplit(){
    String x="test-hi-thank";
String y[]=x.split("-");
    System.out.println(y.length);
}

testSplit();
```

I got this error

```
C:\temp>java -cp bsh-2.0b4.jar bsh.Interpreter test.bsh
Evaluation Error: Parse error at line 3, column 17.  Encountered: [
```

Is there any thing to do?

Outside a class we must do: y=x.split("-");

Answer (score 2):

Beanshell does not support the [] on the variable name, and convention discourages that construct as the brackets are really part of the type, not the variable name.

Thus in Beanshell you have to declare it as follows:

```
String[] y = x.split("-");
```

Because BeashShell is loosely typed you can drop the String[] altogether and it will also work fine. You can also drop a few other things, which free you from the shackles of Java, but, as scripts get more complex, require you to remember more.

```
testSplit(){
   x = "test-hi-thank";
   y = x.split("-");
   System.out.println(y.length);
}

testSplit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem once, and I solved it by using the following strategy:

---

```
public void testSplit(){

    String x="test-hi-thank";
    String first  =x.split("-")[0];
    String second =x.split("-")[1];
    String third  =x.split("-")[2];
}

testSplit();
```

---

Hope it helps.

Clemen.